# In which hindu scripture, savitar(god of speed) is mentioned?

Tags: vedas, vedic-gods, vayupurana

Recently I came across a name Savitar (God of speed). And as a Hindu I never heard this name.So in which scripture we find the description of this deity.

Comment: *Savitaṛ is a solar deity in the **Rigveda**, and possibly one of the Adityas i.e. off-spring of the female Vedic deity Aditi. His name in Vedic Sanskrit connotes "impeller, rouser, vivifier."* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitr

Comment: Savitar As per my knowledge he is god of speed

Comment: I've doubt whether it is [related](https://www.quora.com/Is-savitar-really-a-Hindu-god-of-speed) to Hinduism!